# MSVCP140.dll despite /MT runtime library setting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I tried to run a program I wrote on a remote computer. As I knew there might be a dll problem, I set the runtime library option to /MT, so I can rely on static linking.

However, I still receive the error message on my remote computer, stating that MSCVP140.dll is missing. Isn't this what the /MT flag should take care of?

I even tried to install the redistributable, but no luck. I'm still stuck with the error.

Another thing I tried was placing a MSVCP140.dll I downloaded in the folder, but that way my program is simply crashing on startup. I suspect that the MSCVP140.dll version is not the expected one, so I'm not relying on the validity of this test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Likely a library you are using links dynamically to the CRT. as @TonyThomas says, use depends to find the culprit. Since you often can't change the library, you need to install the respective runtime (not just the DLL, This seems to be the one required: https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: A standard mistake is to change the setting for the Debug configuration but forgetting to also change it for the Release configuration.  A standard mistake deploying the vcredist is to use the wrong one, the difference between the x86 and x64 versions matter.

Comment: @HansPassant I took extra care to install the right version and to set the project settings in the release configuration

Comment: You linked code that was compiled with the wrong setting.  Nobody can find that code for you, consider the linker's /VERBOSE option.

Comment: After going through the file with dependency walker, I think I know which library is responsible. I'll try to see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your exe with depends.exe and find the dependancies in the machine it crashes. Probably the MSVCP140 might have other dependancies. Copy all dependancy dlls into same folder and give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Someone please punch me for being this stupid... I was compiling on x86 instead of x64 all the time. No surprise the dlls didn't work.

Thanks for the help nevertheless. At least you got me on track to take a closer look at my dlls.